# How can I upload multiple files from urls directly to cloud storage

Tags: download, upload, cloud, dropbox

I've tried some of the services out there, including droplet, ctrlq.org/save, and some other sites that support directly fetching a file from a url and uploading it to     dropbox, google drive and the like. Without the user having to store the file on a local disk.

Now the problem is none of these services support multiple urls or batch uploading, but I have quite a few urls and I really need a service where I can put them in, split them with enters or semicolons, and have the files uploaded to dropbox.(or any other cloud storage)

Any help would be gladly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The [Dropbox Saver](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/dropins/saver#creating-buttons) JavaScript control allows you to save up to 100 files to the user's Dropbox in one shot. You'll need to programmatically create the button using `Dropbox.createSaveButton` as explained in the linked page.

Comment: This looks pretty promising, the catch is I've got some 100,000 urls to upload, hopefully that doesn't mean I'd have to make 1000 clicks.

Comment: You might be able to modify the button inside the page and then programatically click() it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the 100-file limit (at any one time) is universal, but you might find that it isn't the case when using the [DropBox REST API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put). It looks possible to do this with [NodeJS](http://www.raweng.com/blog/2014/08/19/file-uploading-in-dropbox-using-node-js/) server side (OAuth and posts) or [Javascript](https://www.newfangled.com/direct-javascript-dropbox-api-usage/) client side (automating FileReader). I'll review and try to add content so these aren't just links.

If you can leave a page open for about 20 minutes due to "technical limitations", the dropbox should be loadable 100-at-a-time like that, assuming each upload takes less than 2 seconds; it's an easy hook to add a progress indicator.

If you're preloading the dropbox once yourself or the initial load is compatible with manual action, perhaps [mapping a drive](http://www.easybow.nl/help/dropbox/scr/Mapping_Dropbox_Site_as_Network_Drive.htm) and trying to unzip an archive of your links to it would work. If your list of links isn't extremely volatile then the REST API could be used to synchronize changes.

Edit: Forgot to include this page on [CloudConvert](https://cloudconvert.com/blog/archive-rar-zip-extraction-inside-google-drive-or-dropbox/), which unzips archives containing up to 100 files into DropBox. Your use case doesn't seem to include retrieving the actual content at your servers (generated zip files), sending the automation list to the browser and then having the browser extract to dropbox, but it's another option.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just think the demand is so intuitive that it could have already been met somewhere, what if I don't have enough bandwidth and need to download files first to a server, then from the server to a local drive during off-peak hours?

Comment: This is the first time I've even thought about this so sorry if I'm not on target: It seems like you'd save bandwidth by having code that redirects the user from Node or JS to the link destinations at the user's browser (which, if saving to a mapped drive would meet the don't save locally requirement; it would just upload to DB from the user), and by local do you mean the user's dropbox? (I might be tired!) I had some luck Googling "bulk upload to dropbox"; URL Droplet seems to take links and perform the correct steps, maybe useful by example?

Comment: I tried and found most cloud storage can indeed be mapped as a local drive, but somehow downloading to the mapped drive hogs more bandwidth, apparently the files aren't directly uploaded to the cloud storage this way.

Comment: I mentioned URL Droplet in the question, it did exactly what I want, the only problem is I want it done in bulk.

Answer (score 0):

The Dropbox API now offers the ability to save a file into Dropbox directly via a URL. There's a blog post about it here:

https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2015/06/programmatically-saving-a-url-to-dropbox/

The documentation can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#save-url